# Get String in YYYYMMDD format from JS date object?

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

I'm trying to use JS to turn a `date object` into a string in `YYYYMMDD` format.  Is there an easier way than concatenating `Date.getYear()`, `Date.getMonth()`, and `Date.getDay()`?

Comment: Concatenating those three is the way to go

Comment: if you want a string that will parse to the same date, don't forget to increment the month. To match your spec you also need to pad single digits in the month and date with '0'

Answer (score 712, accepted):

Altered piece of code I often use:

```
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
  var mm = this.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
  var dd = this.getDate();

  return [this.getFullYear(),
          (mm>9 ? '' : '0') + mm,
          (dd>9 ? '' : '0') + dd
         ].join('');
};

var date = new Date();
date.yyyymmdd();
```

Comment: You should replace `[1]` with `.length===2`, because an indexer on a string is not fully supported. [See this answer for reasons why.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5943760/613176)

Comment: var mm = (this.getMonth() + 101).toStrung().substring(0, 2);

Comment: For anyone wanting a practical example of @Aidiakapi 's fix, I create a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pcr8xbt5/1/

Comment: If you want to have dots separator: `[this.getFullYear(), mm<10 ? '0'+ mm: mm, dd<10 ? '0'+ dd : dd].join('.')`

Comment: @9dan shouldn't it be `var mm = (this.getMonth() + 101).toString().substring(1, 3)`

Comment: @o-o according with w3 school, you only should modify your own prototypes. Never modify the prototypes of standard JavaScript objects like `Date`

Comment: `[]` is pretty safe, nobody is modifying the string character here, and it's only not supported on very old browsers, such as IE7-.

Comment: For people who are really beginners in JS/programming. You can adapt join('') to `join('-')` to get your yyyy-mm-dd format. Just saying.

Comment: Yet another hack ... I dont undestant the upvotes on this thing. *facepalm*

Comment: Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27038188/883603) for a less hacky, more timezone friendly approach.

Answer (score 393):

I didn't like adding to the prototype. An alternative would be:

```js
var rightNow = new Date();
var res = rightNow.toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"");

<!-- Next line is for code snippet output only -->
document.body.innerHTML += res;
```

Comment: If you won't need the `rightNow` variable around, you can wrap `new Date` and get it all back in a single line: `(new Date()).toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"")`

Comment: I wanted `YYYYMMDDHHmmSSsss`, so I did this:  `var ds = (new Date()).toISOString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");`.  Pretty simple, but should be encapsulated.

Comment: This won't work in general as Date.toISOString() creates a UTC formatted date and hence can jump date boundaries depending on the timezone. E.g. in GMT+1: (new Date(2013,13, 25)).toISOString() == '2013-12-24T23:00:00.000Z'

Comment: I ended up using momentjs afterall ;)

Comment: @digiguru could use a polyfill like json2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440569/converting-a-normal-date-to-iso-8601-format

Comment: This would fail if someone in the year 10000 would use your 'nostalgic' code.

Comment: @Aʟᴀɢᴀʀᴏs in that case, `(new Date).toISOString().split('T')[0].replace(/-/g,"");`?

Comment: A suggested improvement to cope with timezones.

`rightNow.setMinutes(rightNow.getMinutes() - rightNow.getTimezoneOffset());

rightNow.toISOString().slice(0,10)`

Comment: As @weberste pointed out, depending on your timezone, this might not work as you expect. So I'll strongly recommend to use the selected answer from o-o .

Comment: I agree with @xarlymg89; I downvoted because this solution would not work if the user's timezone is *ahead* of UTC, right? For example, [most of Europe](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/World_Time_Zones_Map.png) is GMT + 1 as @weberste explains.

Comment: @BigBlueHat You don't have to wrap `new Date()` with brackets, `new`'s execution order is earlier than other operators like `.` and `()`

Answer (score 255):

You can use the `toISOString` function :

```
var today = new Date();
today.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

It will give you a "yyyy-mm-dd" format.

Comment: In some cases this will not include the right day, because of timezone daylight etc...

Comment: Maybe my creativity is broken @Miguel, but I can't think of a case where that would happen. Would you mind providing an example?

Comment: If you are in a +1 timezone, and have a date [2015-09-01 00:00:00 GMT+1], then the toISOString() method will return the string '2015-08-31T23:00:00.000Z' because the date is converted to UTC/0-offset before being stringified.

Comment: A bit shorter... var today = (new Date()).toISOString().substring(0, 10);

Comment: Fails with different GMT

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS. I felt for it once, as you may be near to UTC, it's going to work often and fail one in a while.

Comment: The timezones will ruin it, I am in +3 GMT and I get the date, but it is 3 hours behind

Comment: Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27038188/883603) for a more timezone friendly approach.

Comment: Timezone issue can be fixed with getTimezoneOffset() method: `(date=>new Date(date.valueOf()-60*1000*date.getTimezoneOffset()).toISOString().substring(0, 10))(new Date())`

Answer (score 172):

### [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) could be your friend

```
var date = new Date();
var formattedDate = moment(date).format('YYYYMMDD');
```

Comment: Well it DID add 40kb (minified, non gZip) to my app.js, but I went for it, thanks :).

Comment: best answer so far !

Comment: I don't even bother waiting until I inevitably need moment anymore, I just add it at the start of a project :)

Comment: You can make it easier: `var formattedDate = moment().format('YYYYMMDD');`

Comment: I don't know why I kept dodging this answer but still came back to affirm it's the perfect solution. `Moment.js` is a must have library

Comment: @ns16 For the given example that would work, but in that case it doesn't show how to use it with the date constructor in the case of having a non-now Date object that you're working with.

Comment: There is an alternative in `date-fns` which has a smaller footprint (19.5KB vs 71.9KB gzipped).

Answer (score 55):

```js
new Date('Jun 5 2016').
  toLocaleString('en-us', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'}).
  replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/, '$3-$1-$2');

// => '2016-06-05'
```

Comment: Best soultion  .

Comment: For some reason, needed to add time (even if 00:00) for the conversion to not skip a day back, when I run the formula here, east coast USA. Once I did that, it started working reliably. What I love about this is it can take the input date in multiple formats, so I don't have to worry about that anymore.  `new Date('Sun Mar 31 2019 00:00:00.000').toLocaleString('en-us', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'}).replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/, '$3-$1-$2');`

Answer (score 41):

If you don't need a pure JS solution, you can use jQuery UI to do the job like this :

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('yymmdd', new Date());
```

I usually don't like to import too much libraries. But jQuery UI is so useful, you will probably use it somewhere else in your project.

Visit http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ for more examples

Answer (score 40):

This is a single line of code that you can use to create a `YYYY-MM-DD` string of today's date.

```
var d = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
```

Comment: ^this! FTW! +1.. need to test a bit though.

Comment: Warning tough, if your date was 2016-01-01 00:00:00 GMT +2, it will return **2015-12-31** because `toISOString()` will give 2015-12-31T22:00:00 GMT +0 (two hours before).

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27038188/883603) to work around the timezone issue.

Answer (score 35):

I don't like modifying native objects, and I think multiplication is clearer than the string padding the accepted solution.

```js
function yyyymmdd(dateIn) {
  var yyyy = dateIn.getFullYear();
  var mm = dateIn.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
  var dd = dateIn.getDate();
  return String(10000 * yyyy + 100 * mm + dd); // Leading zeros for mm and dd
}

var today = new Date();
console.log(yyyymmdd(today));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gbdarren/Ew7Y4/

Comment: This answer was downvoted, and I don't know why. I felt math is faster and clearer than string manipulation. If anyone knows why this is a bad answer, please let me know.

Comment: The 10000 multiplicator is there to shift left the YYYY by 4 places (month and day digits needs 2 digits each) and has nothing to do with the Y10K bug. I like this answer and it deserve respect!

Comment: Thanks for this answer I created the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/amwebexpert/L6j0omb4/

Comment: I did not need the multiplication at all and I don't understand why it is there.  http://jsfiddle.net/navyjax2/gbqmv0t5/  Otherwise, leave that out, and this is a great answer and helped me a lot.

Comment: @vapcguy : The multiplication is there to avoid string concatenation. It shifts the year and month to the left. Your solution works as well, but it concatenates strings. I haven't run tests, but it is likely slower.

Comment: @D-Money Ah, I figured out what you mean - you're doing a concatenation of a different sort by adding the numbers together to avoid them doing a different math operation on each other - an operation to disallow the normal one that would've otherwise messed them up. Good job! Mine works because I'm using separators (which I'd have to do a `.replace('-', '')` on to make it answer the OP's question), whereas you were true to the OP's original question and it would not require that extra step. Excellent!

Comment: Definitely the best answer.

Comment: Answer would be perfect if (as of 2020) `var` would be replaced by `let` as it's function scoped here

Answer (score 31):

Local time:

```
var date = new Date();
date = date.toJSON().slice(0, 10);
```

UTC time:

```
var date = new Date().toISOString();
date = date.substring(0, 10);
```

date will print 2020-06-15 today as i write this.

toISOString() method returns the date with the ISO standard which is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

The code takes the first 10 characters that we need for a YYYY-MM-DD format.

If you want format without '-' use:

```
var date = new Date();
date = date.toJSON().slice(0, 10).split`-`.join``;
```

In .join`` you can add space, dots or whatever you'd like.

Comment: WRONG. As `.toISOString();` will return UTC time. So depending on the time and your timezone, the final date you will get can be +1 or -1 day

Comment: Edited. You are right. Using ' var date = new Date();
date = date.toJSON().slice(0, 10); ' Gives local time.

Comment: Does not give local time.

Comment: Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27038188/883603) for a solution that **does take the localized time into account**.

Answer (score 27):

In addition to o-o's answer I'd like to recommend separating logic operations from the return and put them as ternaries in the variables instead.

Also, use `concat()` to ensure safe concatenation of variables

```js
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
  var yyyy = this.getFullYear();
  var mm = this.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" + (this.getMonth() + 1) : (this.getMonth() + 1); // getMonth() is zero-based
  var dd = this.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + this.getDate() : this.getDate();
  return "".concat(yyyy).concat(mm).concat(dd);
};

Date.prototype.yyyymmddhhmm = function() {
  var yyyymmdd = this.yyyymmdd();
  var hh = this.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + this.getHours() : this.getHours();
  var min = this.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + this.getMinutes() : this.getMinutes();
  return "".concat(yyyymmdd).concat(hh).concat(min);
};

Date.prototype.yyyymmddhhmmss = function() {
  var yyyymmddhhmm = this.yyyymmddhhmm();
  var ss = this.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + this.getSeconds() : this.getSeconds();
  return "".concat(yyyymmddhhmm).concat(ss);
};

var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = d.yyyymmdd();
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = d.yyyymmddhhmm();
document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = d.yyyymmddhhmmss();
```

```html
<div>
  yyyymmdd: <span id="a"></span>
</div>
<div>
  yyyymmddhhmm: <span id="b"></span>
</div>
<div>
  yyyymmddhhmmss: <span id="c"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: If someone likes to use that, I suggest DRY here, reuse the already created functions instead of doing the same all over again.

Comment: @RiZKiT DRY is a principle and not a pattern but sure, this can be improved a lot. If I where to use this myself I'd probably use another pattern and move the methods away from the prototype. I mainly wrote the example to show there where other ways to solve the problem. Where people take it from there is up to themselves

Comment: Nice!

I use `("00" + (this.getDate())).slice(-2)` to get the numbers two-digits based. There is no "if" or "?:" statement, and less calls to the .getX() function.

If not a little bit faster, it’s at least more readable.

Answer (score 24):

**Plain JS (ES5) solution without any possible date jump issues caused by Date.toISOString() printing in UTC:**

```
var now = new Date();
var todayUTC = new Date(Date.UTC(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()));
return todayUTC.toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '');
```

This in response to @weberste's comment on @Pierre Guilbert's answer.

Comment: now.getMonth() will return 0 for January, it should be (now.getMonth() + 1)

Comment: Wrong. Date's UTC function expects month to be between 0 and 11 (but other < 0 and > 11 is allowed).

Comment: Why do you replace multiple hyphens by a single one? Can `toISOString` return multiple successive hyphens?

Comment: Michael -- he is replacing *each* hyphen found with a single hyphen.  Still don't know why (perhaps the replacement string is just a place holder for a separator).  The 'g' means all occurrences.  The pattern you are thinking of is /[-]+/g

Comment: Changed the replace with hyphen to empty char, to match OP's question.

Comment: You made my day. I've been searching for days for a simple way to bypass the horrible TimeZone handling in Javascript, and this does the trick!

Answer (score 12):

```js
// UTC/GMT 0
document.write('UTC/GMT 0: ' + (new Date()).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")); // 20150812013509

// Client local time
document.write('<br/>Local time: ' + (new Date(Date.now()-(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")); // 20150812113509
```

Comment: This is the answer I used. One liner that takes into account the time zone. To answer the original poster's question, we could do: 
(new Date(Date.now()-(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").slice(0,8)

Comment: thx, to get YYYY-MM-DD i used: new Date(Date.now()-(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/[^0-9]/g, "-")

Comment: @Kus how can i get milliseconds well?

Answer (score 12):

Another way is to use [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) with a locale that has a [big-endian date format standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#Gregorian.2C_year-month-day_.28YMD.29), such as Sweden, Lithuania, Hungary, South Korea, ...:

```
date.toLocaleDateString('se')
```

To remove the delimiters (`-`) is just a matter of replacing the non-digits:

```js
console.log( new Date().toLocaleDateString('se').replace(/\D/g, '') );
```

This does not have the potential error you can get with UTC date formats: the UTC date may be one day off compared to the date in the local time zone.

Answer (score 10):

```js
var someDate = new Date();
var dateFormated = someDate.toISOString().substr(0,10);

console.log(dateFormated);
```

Comment: Won't work since new Date() has a timezone and Date.toISOString() is UTC. See my answer.

Comment: @Dormouse isn't it the other way around? `new Date()` creates a new date object which is just a wrapper around nr. of ms since 1970/01/01 00:00:00.000 UTC. Then `toISOString` prints out in local timezone.

Comment: Nope, Date.toISOString() prints in UTC.

Answer (score 8):

[**dateformat**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat) is a very used package.

*How to use:*

Download and install `dateformat` from NPM. Require it in your module:

`const dateFormat = require('dateformat');`

and then just format your stuff:

`const myYYYYmmddDate = dateformat(new Date(), 'yyyy-mm-dd');`

Answer (score 8):

A little variation for the accepted answer:

```js
function getDate_yyyymmdd() {

    const date = new Date();

    const yyyy = date.getFullYear();
    const mm = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2,'0');
    const dd = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2,'0');

    return `${yyyy}${mm}${dd}`
}

console.log(getDate_yyyymmdd())
```

Answer (score 6):

Working from @o-o's answer this will give you back the string of the date according to a format string. You can easily add a 2 digit year regex for the year & milliseconds and the such if you need them.

```
Date.prototype.getFromFormat = function(format) {
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
    format = format.replace(/yyyy/g, yyyy)
    var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); 
    format = format.replace(/mm/g, (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]));
    var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
    format = format.replace(/dd/g, (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]));
    var hh = this.getHours().toString();
    format = format.replace(/hh/g, (hh[1]?hh:"0"+hh[0]));
    var ii = this.getMinutes().toString();
    format = format.replace(/ii/g, (ii[1]?ii:"0"+ii[0]));
    var ss  = this.getSeconds().toString();
    format = format.replace(/ss/g, (ss[1]?ss:"0"+ss[0]));
    return format;
};

d = new Date();
var date = d.getFromFormat('yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss');
alert(date);
```

I don't know how efficient that is however, especially perf wise because it uses a lot of regex. It could probably use some work I do not master pure js.

NB: I've kept the predefined class definition but you might wanna put that in a function or a custom class as per best practices.

Answer (score 6):

## Shortest

```
.toJSON().slice(0,10).split`-`.join``;
```

```js
let d = new Date();

let s = d.toJSON().slice(0,10).split`-`.join``;

console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 5):

This guy here => http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format wrote a `format()` function for the Javascript's `Date` object, so it can be used with familiar literal formats.

If you need full featured Date formatting in your app's Javascript, use it. Otherwise if what you want to do is a one off, then concatenating getYear(), getMonth(), getDay() is probably easiest.

Answer (score 5):

Little bit simplified version for the most popular answer in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/3067896/5437379 :

```
function toYYYYMMDD(d) {
    var yyyy = d.getFullYear().toString();
    var mm = (d.getMonth() + 101).toString().slice(-2);
    var dd = (d.getDate() + 100).toString().slice(-2);
    return yyyy + mm + dd;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use This one line code to get date in year

```
var date = new Date().getFullYear() + "-" + (parseInt(new Date().getMonth()) + 1) + "-" + new Date().getDate();
```

Answer (score 5):

How about **Day.js**?

It's only 2KB, and you can also `dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD')`.

https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs

Answer (score 5):

Use **padStart**:

```
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
    return [
        this.getFullYear(),
        (this.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0'), // getMonth() is zero-based
        this.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')
    ].join('-');
};
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[day,,month,,year]= Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }).formatToParts(new Date()),year.value+month.value+day.value
```

or

```
new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).replace(/\/|-/g,'')
```

Comment: This was super close for me, but the order of `DateTimeFormat` was different. I suspect it is localized.

Comment: Second line is wrong. As `.toISOString();` will return UTC time. So depending on the time and your timezone, the final date you will get can be +1 or -1 day

Answer (score 4):

This code is fix to Pierre Guilbert's answer:

(it works even after 10000 years)

```
YYYYMMDD=new Date().toISOString().slice(0,new Date().toISOString().indexOf("T")).replace(/-/g,"")
```

Answer (score 4):

Answering another for Simplicity & readability.
Also, editing existing predefined class members with new methods is not encouraged:

```
function getDateInYYYYMMDD() {
    let currentDate = new Date();

    // year
    let yyyy = '' + currentDate.getFullYear();

    // month
    let mm = ('0' + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1));  // prepend 0 // +1 is because Jan is 0
    mm = mm.substr(mm.length - 2);                  // take last 2 chars

    // day
    let dd = ('0' + currentDate.getDate());         // prepend 0
    dd = dd.substr(dd.length - 2);                  // take last 2 chars

    return yyyy + "" + mm + "" + dd;
}

var currentDateYYYYMMDD = getDateInYYYYMMDD();
console.log('currentDateYYYYMMDD: ' + currentDateYYYYMMDD);
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that mootools provides `Date().format()`: https://mootools.net/more/docs/1.6.0/Types/Date

I'm not sure if it worth including just for this particular task though.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use the code below when I need to do this.

```
var date = new Date($.now());
var dateString = (date.getFullYear() + '-'
    + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
    + '-' + ('0' + (date.getDate())).slice(-2));
console.log(dateString); //Will print "2015-09-18" when this comment was written
```

To explain, .slice(-2) gives us the last two characters of the string.

So no matter what, we can add "0" to the day or month, and just ask for the last two since those are always the two we want.

So if the MyDate.getMonth() returns 9, it will be:

```
("0" + "9") // Giving us "09"
```

so adding .slice(-2) on that gives us the last two characters which is:

```
("0" + "9").slice(-2)

"09"
```

But if date.getMonth() returns 10, it will be:

```
("0" + "10") // Giving us "010"
```

so adding .slice(-2) gives us the last two characters, or:

```
("0" + "10").slice(-2)

"10"
```

Answer (score 3):

From ES6 onwards you can use template strings to make it a little shorter:

```
var now = new Date();
var todayString = `${now.getFullYear()}-${now.getMonth()}-${now.getDate()}`;
```

This solution does not zero pad. Look to the other good answers to see how to do that.

Comment: There are two bugs in your code: 1) you don't account for the fact that `getMonth()` is zero-based and 2) you don't pad with zeros. In sum, "Jan 1, 2020" will result in `2020-0-1` which is far from ideal.

Comment: Many many techniques for zero padding has been shown in the other answers, I really just wanted to show the template strings. But I will add a disclaimer to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
const date = new Date()

console.log(date.toISOString().split('T')[0]) // 2022-12-27
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind including an additional (but small) library, [Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/) provides lots of nice functionality for working with [dates](http://sugarjs.com/dates) in JavaScript.
To format a date, use the [format](http://sugarjs.com/api/Date/format) function:

```
new Date().format("{yyyy}{MM}{dd}")
```

Answer (score 2):

If using AngularJs (up to 1.5) you can use the [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date):

```
var formattedDate = $filter('date')(myDate, 'yyyyMMdd')
```

Comment: So, in order to format one variable, he needs to refactoring the whole application from whatever to AngularJS?

Comment: @SangDang The OP mentions Javascript in the question. All answers are giving different Javascript possibilities. Javascript based frameworks are one possible answer.

Answer (score 2):

```js
yyyymmdd=x=>(f=x=>(x<10&&'0')+x,x.getFullYear()+f(x.getMonth()+1)+f(x.getDate()));
alert(yyyymmdd(new Date));
```

Comment: adding some description to your answer will get you upvotes try to describe a bit what you are doing in this code so others can understand it more clearly.

Comment: In strict mode or typescript use "let f,yyyymmdd=x=>..." instead. Functions yyyymmdd and f are otherwise undefined.

Answer (score 2):

[date-shortcode](https://github.com/kodie/date-shortcode) to the rescue!

```
const dateShortcode = require('date-shortcode')
dateShortcode.parse('{YYYYMMDD}', new Date())
//=> '20180304'
```

Answer (score 2):

A lot of answers here use the toisostring function. This function converts the time to zulu time before outputting, which may cause issues.

```
function datestring(time) {
    return new Date(time.getTime() - time.getTimezoneOffset()*60000).toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"")
}

mydate = new Date("2018-05-03")
console.log(datestring(mydate))
```

The datestring function fixes the timezone issue, or even better you can avoid the whole issue by working in zulu time:

```
mydate = new Date("2018-05-03Z")
// mydate = new Date(Date.UTC(2018,5,3))
console.log(mydate.toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generic approach which allows both *date* and *time* components and is identically sortable as either number or string.

Based on the number order of Date ISO format, convert to a local timezone and remove non-digits. i.e.:

```
// monkey patch version
Date.prototype.IsoNum = function (n) {
    var tzoffset = this.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; //offset in milliseconds
    var localISOTime = (new Date(this - tzoffset)).toISOString().slice(0,-1);
    return localISOTime.replace(/[-T:\.Z]/g, '').substring(0,n || 20); // YYYYMMDD
}
```

**Usage**

```
var d = new Date();
// Tue Jul 28 2015 15:02:53 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
console.log(d.IsoNum(8));  // "20150728"
console.log(d.IsoNum(12)); // "201507281502"
console.log(d.IsoNum());   // "20150728150253272"
```

Answer (score 1):

Native Javascript:

```
new Date().toLocaleString('zu-ZA').slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'');
```

Comment: This does not pad months with a 0 to ensure the month be 2 digits.

Comment: You're right. I later noticed this myself. You've got to be careful testing out date formatting on double digit months and days.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can build a specific function for each variation of date string representations. If you consider international date formats you wind up with dozens of specific functions with rediculous names and hard to distinguish.

There is no reasonable function that matches all formats, but there is a reasonable function composition that does:

```js
const pipe2 = f => g => x =>
  g(f(x));

const pipe3 = f => g => h => x =>
  h(g(f(x)));

const invoke = (method, ...args) => o =>
  o[method] (...args);

const padl = (c, n) => s =>
  c.repeat(n)
    .concat(s)
    .slice(-n);

const inc = n => n + 1;

// generic format date function

const formatDate = stor => (...args) => date =>
  args.map(f => f(date))
    .join(stor);

// MAIN

const toYYYYMMDD = formatDate("") (
  invoke("getFullYear"),
  pipe3(invoke("getMonth")) (inc) (padl("0", 2)),
  pipe2(invoke("getDate")) (padl("0", 2)));

console.log(toYYYYMMDD(new Date()));
```

Yes, this is a lot of code. But you can express literally every string date representation by simply changing the function arguments passed to the higher order function `formatDate`. Everything is explicit and declarative i.e., you can almost read what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

### One Liner (2022) w/ Correct Timezone Offset

```
var dateDisplay = new Date(Date.now() - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 1000 * 60)).toJSON().slice(0, 10).replaceAll("-", "");
```

```js
// YearMonthDay

var dateDisplay = new Date(Date.now() - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 1000 * 60)).toJSON().slice(0, 10).replaceAll("-", "");

console.log("YearMonthDay");
console.log(dateDisplay);

// Year-Month-Day

var dateDisplay = new Date(Date.now() - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 1000 * 60)).toJSON().slice(0, 10);

console.log("Year-Month-Day");
console.log(dateDisplay);

// Year-Month-Day Hour:Minute:Second

var dateDisplay = new Date(Date.now() - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 1000 * 60)).toJSON().slice(0, 19).replace("T", " ");

console.log("Year-Month-Day Hour:Minute:Second");
console.log(dateDisplay);

// Year-Month-Day Hour-Minute-Second

var dateDisplay = new Date(Date.now() - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 1000 * 60)).toJSON().slice(0, 19).replace("T", " ").replaceAll(":", "-");

console.log("Year-Month-Day Hour-Minute-Second");
console.log(dateDisplay);

// ISO-8601 standard: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ

var dateDisplay = new Date(Date.now() - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 1000 * 60)).toJSON();

console.log("ISO-8601 standard: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ");
console.log(dateDisplay);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written a simple function, which can convert a `Date` object to `String` with **date number**, **month number** (with *zero padding*) and **year number** in customizable order. You can use it with any **separator** you like or leave this parameter empty to have no **separator** in output. Please, have a look.

```js
function dateToString(date, $1, $2, $3, separator='') {
  const dateObj = {
    date: String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0'),
    month: String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'),
    year: date.getFullYear()
  };

  return dateObj[$1] + separator + dateObj[$2] + separator + dateObj[$3];
}

const date = new Date();

const dateString1 = dateToString(date, 'year', 'month', 'date');
console.log(dateString1);

// Manipulate arguments order to get output you want
const dateString2 = dateToString(date, 'date', 'month', 'year', '-');
console.log(dateString2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little improvement to the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/318563/o-o

```
Date.prototype.ddmmyyyy = function(delimiter) {
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
    var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
    var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
    return (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]) + delimiter + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + delimiter +yyyy  ; // padding
};
```

Hope to be helpfull for anyone!

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
```

function showdate(){

```
var a = new Date();
var b = a.getFullYear();
var c = a.getMonth();
(++c < 10)? c = "0" + c : c;
var d = a.getDate();
(d < 10)? d = "0" + d : d;
var final = b + "-" + c + "-" + d; 

return final;


} 

document.getElementById("todays_date").innerHTML = showdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

this post helped me to write this helper, so I share it in case some one
is looking for this solution, it supports all variations of yyyy, mm, dd

```
Date.prototype.formattedDate = function (pattern) {
    formattedDate = pattern.replace('yyyy', this.getFullYear().toString());
    var mm = (this.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
    mm = mm.length > 1 ? mm : '0' + mm;
    formattedDate = formattedDate.replace('mm', mm);
    var dd = this.getDate().toString();
    dd = dd.length > 1 ? dd : '0' + dd;
    formattedDate = formattedDate.replace('dd', dd);
    return formattedDate;
};

d = new Date();
pattern = 'yyyymmdd';  // 20150813
d.formattedDate(pattern);

pattern = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
d.formattedDate(pattern); // 2015-08-13
```

Answer (score 0):

Date.js has a lot of helpful date parsing methods.

`require("datejs")`

`(new Date()).toString("yyyyMMdd")`

Answer (score 0):

I try to write a simple library for manipulating JavaScript date object. You can try this.

```
var dateString = timeSolver.getString(date, "YYYYMMDD")
```

Libarary here:
https://github.com/sean1093/timeSolver

Comment: `newDate = timeSolver.add(newDate, 1, 'd');  
   date = timeSolver.getString(newDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');`  
Resulted in a bad formatted date like 2017-6-9

Comment: @Magnus Thanks for informing! Will be modify soon.

Comment: Fix that, please try version 1.0.7 thanks!
https://github.com/sean1093/timeSolver

Answer (score 0):

Nice, and easy:

```
    var date = new Date();
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
    var mm = date.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
    if (mm < 10) mm='0'+mm;
    var dd = date.getDate();
    if (dd < 10) dd='0'+dd;
    /*date.yyyymmdd();*/

    console.log('test - '+yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd);
```

Answer (score 0):

The @o-o solution doesn't work in my case.
My solution is the following:

```
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
  var mm = this.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
  var dd = this.getDate();
  var ret = [this.getFullYear(), (mm<10)?'0':'', mm, (dd<10)?'0':'', dd].join('');

  return ret; // padding
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the local date, in a YYYYMMDD format, im using:

```
var todayDate = (new Date()).toLocaleString('en-GB').slice(0,10).split("\/").reverse().join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create yourself function as below

```
function toString(o, regex) {
    try {
        if (!o) return '';
        if (typeof o.getMonth === 'function' && !!regex) {
            let splitChar = regex.indexOf('/') > -1 ? '/' : regex.indexOf('-') > -1 ? '-' : regex.indexOf('.') > -1 ? '.' : '';
            let dateSeparate = regex.split(splitChar);
            let result = '';
            for (let item of dateSeparate) {
                let val = '';
                switch (item) {
                    case 'd':
                        val = o.getDate();
                        break;
                    case 'dd':
                        val = this.date2Char(o.getDate());
                        break;
                    case 'M':
                        val = o.getMonth() + 1;
                        break;
                    case 'MM':
                        val = this.date2Char(o.getMonth() + 1);
                        break;
                    case 'yyyy':
                        val = o.getFullYear();
                        break;
                    case 'yy':
                        val = this.date2Char(o.getFullYear());
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                result += val + splitChar;
            }
            return result.substring(0, result.length - 1);
        } else {
            return o.toString();
        }
    } catch(ex) { return ''; }
}

function concatDateToString(args) {
    if (!args.length) return '';
    let result = '';
    for (let i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
        result += args[i] + args[0];
    }
    return result.substring(0, result.length - 1);
}

function date2Char(d){
    return this.rightString('0' + d);
}

function rightString(o) {
    return o.substr(o.length - 2);
}
```

Used:

```
var a = new Date();
console.log('dd/MM/yyyy: ' + toString(a, 'dd/MM/yyyy'));
console.log('MM/dd/yyyy: ' + toString(a, 'MM/dd/yyyy'));
console.log('dd/MM/yy: ' + toString(a, 'dd/MM/yy'));
console.log('MM/dd/yy: ' + toString(a, 'MM/dd/yy'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this function will be useful

```
function formatDate(dDate,sMode){       
        var today = dDate;
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if(dd<10) {
            dd = '0'+dd
        } 
        if(mm<10) {
            mm = '0'+mm
        } 
        if (sMode+""==""){
            sMode = "dd/mm/yyyy";
        }
        if (sMode == "yyyy-mm-dd"){
            return  yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd + "";
        }
        if (sMode == "dd/mm/yyyy"){
            return  dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a compact little function that's easy to read and avoids local variables, which can be time-sinks in JavaScript.  I don't use prototypes to alter standard modules, because it pollutes the namespace and can lead to code that doesn't do what you think it should.

The main function has a stupid name, but it gets the idea across.

```
function dateToYYYYMMDDhhmmss(date) {
    function pad(num) {
        num = num + '';
        return num.length < 2 ? '0' + num : num;
    }
    return date.getFullYear() + '/' +
        pad(date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +
        pad(date.getDate()) + ' ' +
        pad(date.getHours()) + ':' +
        pad(date.getMinutes()) + ':' +
        pad(date.getSeconds());
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. I think the questions is about how to avoid the `date.getMonth()`, `Date`, etc.

Comment: Thanks!  I know.  I'm just tossing in my two cents.

Comment: @AaronEndelman Your pad function could be simplified to just return ('0' + num).slice(-2) :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
var dateDisplay = new Date( 2016-11-09 05:27:00 UTC );
dateDisplay = dateDisplay.toString()
var arr = (dateDisplay.split(' '))
var date_String =  arr[0]+','+arr[1]+' '+arr[2]+' '+arr[3]+','+arr[4]
```

this will show string like Wed,Nov 09 2016,10:57:00

Comment: This solution is way too _hack-ish_. Avoid at all cost

Answer (score -1):

```
<pre>Date.prototype.getFromFormat = function(format) {
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
    format = format.replace(/yyyy/g, yyyy)
    var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); 
    format = format.replace(/mm/g, (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]));
    var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
    format = format.replace(/dd/g, (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]));
    var hh = this.getHours().toString();
    format = format.replace(/hh/g, (hh[1]?hh:"0"+hh[0]));
    var ii = this.getMinutes().toString();
    format = format.replace(/ii/g, (ii[1]?ii:"0"+ii[0]));
    var ss  = this.getSeconds().toString();
    format = format.replace(/ss/g, (ss[1]?ss:"0"+ss[0]));
    var ampm = (hh >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
    format = format.replace(/ampm/g, (ampm[1]?ampm:"0"+ampm[0]));
    return format;
};
var time_var = $('#899_TIME');
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date(); 
    var date = d.getFromFormat('dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii:ss:ampm');
    time_var.text(date);

} </pre>

use the code and get the output like **26-07-2017 12:29:34:PM**

check the below link for your reference

https://parthiban037.wordpress.com/2017/07/26/date-and-time-format-in-oracle-apex-using-javascript/
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written