# Format date in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

```
var date = "Fri Jan 29 2012 06:12:00 GMT+0100";
```

How can i show this in format **2012-01-29 06:12** ?
In PHP is function ->format. In Javascript is also format, but if i try use this then i have error:

**now.format is not a function**

```
var now = new Date();
console.log(now.format("isoDateTime"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6v9hD/

I would like receive format:  **2012-01-29 06:12**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current date in jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398897/how-to-get-current-date-in-jquery)

Comment: Not a duplicate because this post includes time formatting

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This question is a duplicate (see: [How to get current date in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398897/how-to-get-current-date-in-jquery)).

By modifying [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8398929/548696) from the other question, I got:

```
var d = new Date();

var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var hour = d.getHours();
var minute = d.getMinutes();
var second = d.getSeconds();

var output = d.getFullYear() + '-' +
    ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
    ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + ' ' +
    ((''+hour).length<2 ? '0' :'') + hour + ':' +
    ((''+minute).length<2 ? '0' :'') + minute + ':' +
    ((''+second).length<2 ? '0' :'') + second;
```

See this jsfiddle for a proof: http://jsfiddle.net/nCE9u/3/

You can also enclose it within function (demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nCE9u/4/):

```
function getISODateTime(d){
    // padding function
    var s = function(a,b){return(1e15+a+"").slice(-b)};

    // default date parameter
    if (typeof d === 'undefined'){
        d = new Date();
    };

    // return ISO datetime
    return d.getFullYear() + '-' +
        s(d.getMonth()+1,2) + '-' +
        s(d.getDate(),2) + ' ' +
        s(d.getHours(),2) + ':' +
        s(d.getMinutes(),2) + ':' +
        s(d.getSeconds(),2);
}
```

and use it like that:

```
getISODateTime(new Date());
```

or:

```
getISODateTime(some_other_date);
```

**EDIT:** I have added some improvement to the function, as proposed by Ates Goral (also decreased its readability in favour of code comments).

Comment: My goodness. This is one verbose implementation :/ You could at least use a local function for the padding: `function pad(n) { return n < 10 ? n : ("0" + n); }`

Comment: @AtesGoral: You are right about internal function - I have refactored this code. For consistency reasons I made it return string at all times (in your case sometimes it would be an integer). Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: This is nice and really should be the first answer that pops up when searching for formatting JS dateTime. Can't believe vanilla JS doesn't have something like this built in - it's crazy we have to have a big-ass function to do something this simple! :P

Answer (score 6):

[Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).[toString](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#toString)('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') should do the trick

Comment: thanks, but i must use object created with clear javascript - new Date().

Comment: @Mark Fondy - it will hijack the Date prototype; so no worries.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, in Javascript, Date does not have a format() method.

Check out http://fisforformat.sourceforge.net for some nice formatting methods.

Answer (score 3):

Use a library like [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) or perhaps this [tweet-sized](http://140byt.es/) implementation:

https://gist.github.com/1005948

```
var str = formatDate(
    new Date(),
    "{FullYear}-{Month:2}-{Date:2} {Hours:2}:{Minutes:2}");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be help you:[date.format.js](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

```
var now = new Date();
now.format("m/dd/yy");
// Returns, e.g., 6/09/07
// Can also be used as a standalone function
dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
// Saturday, June 9th, 2007, 5:46:21 PM
// You can use one of several named masks
now.format("isoDateTime");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this(include [date.js](https://code.google.com/archive/p/datejs/wikis/APIDocumentation.wiki) ) :

```
Date.parse(yourDate).toISOString();
```

so the date will have ISO 8601 format.