# Jquery code to insert current date time in to database

Tags: jquery

am new to Jquery.
I want to insert current date time to Db

```
var data{
"id":1,
 "name":"mybane",
"datetime":// here i have to put current date time
}
```

is there any possible way to get the current date time..

Comment: Have you tried looking anywhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get datetime in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744299/how-to-get-datetime-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
var data{
"id":1,
 "name":"mybane",
"datetime":new Date(),
}
```

Reference: [How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9050848/829533

All you need to do is to use this `output` variable in your `datetime:` param

```
var d = new Date();

var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var hour = d.getHours();
var minute = d.getMinutes();
var second = d.getSeconds();

var output = d.getFullYear() + '-' +
    ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
    ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + ' ' +
    ((''+hour).length<2 ? '0' :'') + hour + ':' +
    ((''+minute).length<2 ? '0' :'') + minute + ':' +
    ((''+second).length<2 ? '0' :'') + second;
```

**In action** http://jsfiddle.net/nCE9u/3/

Other then this you can sent the direct your database related function to add current time stamp like the one `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` (in mysql)

Note: you can send this as an string

```
"datetime" : "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()"
```

And give it directly to the database as a string.

Answer (score 1):

use **[new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)**

```
var data{
"id":1,
 "name":"mybane",
"datetime":new Date()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var currentTime = new Date();

var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();

var date1 = month + "/" + day + "/" + year; // output
```

**take your required value from below function :**

- getTime() - Number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 @ 12:00 AM
- getSeconds() - Number of seconds (0-59)
- getMinutes() - Number of minutes (0-59)
- getHours() - Number of hours (0-23)
- getDay() - Day of the week(0-6). 0 = Sunday, ... , 6 = Saturday
- getDate() - Day of the month (0-31)
- getMonth() - Number of month (0-11)
- getFullYear() - The four digit year (1970-9999)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var d=new Date();
 var time=d.getTime();
```

This is the function you can use to get current time

Answer (score 0):

Create Date object and format as you need:

```
var data{
"id":1,
 "name":"mybane",
"datetime":(function(d) { return d.format('dd.mm.yyyy hh:MM') })(new Date());
}
```