# Set default time in bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I want to set default time in [this datetimepicker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) as `00:01` for the current date. Anyone tried that before? Having a tough time with it. It Seems simple.

```
$('#startdatetime-from').datetimepicker({
    language: 'en',
    format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'
});
```

I need to use `setDate`, but I'm not sure how. I checked their code, but did not find a parameter for that.

Comment: why don't you show us what you are having trouble with.  Post some code.

Comment: See my updated answer for [setDate/setLocalDate](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#api).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Set a default input value as per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/8).

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="datetimepicker-input"></input>
```

jQuery

```
var d = new Date();

var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();

var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
(month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
(day<10 ? '0' : '') + day;

$("#datetimepicker-input").val(output + " 00:01:00");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CujDK/4/)
[JavaScript date source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8398929/1684247)

**EDIT** - setLocalDate/setDate

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();

$('#startdatetime-from').datetimepicker({
    language: 'en',
    format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'
});
$("#startdatetime-from").data('DateTimePicker').setLocalDate(new Date(year, month, day, 00, 01));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CujDK/5/)

Comment: for me .setDate() worked instead of setLocalDate(). Thanks anyway!

Comment: There are some typos in the code. Correct code is actually: `jQuery('#startDate').data('DateTimePicker').setDate(new Date(2015, 1, 1, 00, 01));`

Comment: Your github link seems to be broken now.

Comment: What if i want add editable time zone in datetime picker?

Comment: @M.AhmadZafar how you use .setDate() because when i tried to use i go an error like Cannot read property 'setLocalDate' of undefined

Answer (score 41):

None of the above worked for me, however I had success setting the default at time of instantiation.

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var dateNow = new Date();
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            defaultDate:dateNow
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate)

Answer (score 12):

For use datetime from input value, just set option useCurrent to false, and set in value the date

```html
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  useCurrent: false,
  format: 'DD.MM.YYYY H:mm'
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I set `useCurrent` to `false`, then `defaultDate` worked.

Comment: Beware that the format string accepted by datetimepicker is not the same as a C# datetime format string. For example, to set the value on the input in .Net MVC, use `<input type="text" id="datetimepicker1" value="@Model.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy H:MM")"/>` (note the different casing of "dd" and "yyyy")

Comment: that useCurrent saved me... could not work out how to stop it - thanks!

Comment: Perfect, I have just set value format same as datepicker and it worked great.

Answer (score 9):

i tried to set default time for a picker and it worked:

```
$('#date2').datetimepicker({
 format: 'DD-MM-YYYY 12:00:00'
});
```

this will save in database as : 2015-03-01 12:00:00

used for `smalldatetime` type in sql server

Comment: This also disables hour and minute selection. You won't have option to change hours or minutes.

Answer (score 8):

It works for me:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var dateNow = new Date();
            $('#calendario').datetimepicker({
                locale: 'es',
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                defaultDate:moment(dateNow).hours(0).minutes(0).seconds(0).milliseconds(0)                    
            });
        });            
    </script>
```

Comment: this should be the perfect answer

Answer (score 7):

use this after initialisation

```
$('.form_datetime').datetimepicker('update', new Date());
```

Answer (score 5):

**Hello developers,**

**Please try this code**

```
var default_date=  new Date(); // or your date
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm', // format you want to show on datetimepicker
    useCurrent:false, // default this is set to true
    defaultDate: default_date
});
```

if you want to set default date then please set useCurrent to false otherwise setDate or defaultDate like methods will not work.

Answer (score 4):

This Works for me. I have to use specially date format like this 'YY-MM-dd hh:mm' or 'YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm'

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm',
            defaultDate: new Date()
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution for your problem :

```
$('#startdatetime-from').datetimepicker({
language: 'en',
format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'
}).on('dp.change', function (e) {
        var specifiedDate = new Date(e.date);
        if (specifiedDate.getMinutes() == 0)
        {
            specifiedDate.setMinutes(1);
            $(this).data('DateTimePicker').date(specifiedDate);
        }
    });
```

This also work for setting a default hour or both.
Note that this code sample works with the `useCurrent: false` parameter too.

When the user pick a date, we check if the minute is 0 (hard-coded default value). In this case, we set a 1. Then, the user cannot select 0.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem like this

```
$('#startdatetime-from').datetimepicker({
language: 'en',
format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm',
defaultDate:new Date()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Momentjs.com has good documentation on how to manipulate the date/time in relation to the current moment.  Since Momentjs is required for the Datetimepicker, might as well use it.

```
var startDefault = moment().startof('day').add(1, 'minutes');
$('#startdatetime-from').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: startDefault,
    language: 'en',
    format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com), i able to set the default time

```
var defaultStartTime = moment(new Date());
var _startTimeStr = "02:00 PM"


    if (moment(_startTimeStr, 'HH:mm a').isValid()) {
        var hr = moment(_startTimeStr, 'HH:mm a').hour();
        var min = moment(_startTimeStr, 'HH:mm a').minutes();

        defaultStartTime = defaultStartTime.hours(hr).minutes(min);
    }

$('#StartTime').datetimepicker({
    pickDate: false,
    defaultDate: defaultStartTime
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me after a long hours of search , This solution is for Bootstrap datetimepicker version 4. when you have to set the default date in input field.

HTML

```
"input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker5' placeholder="Select to date" value='<?php echo $myDate?>'// $myDate is having value '2016-02-23' "
```

Note- If You are coding in php then you can set the value of the input datefield using php, but datetimepicker sets it back to current date when you apply datetimepicker() function to it. So in order to prevent it, use the given JS code

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
$('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
           useCurrent: false //this is important as the functions sets the default date value to the current value 
           ,format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });
</script>
```