# How can I correctly set the default value for bootstrap 3 datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am trying to set the default date/time for a [bootstrap 3 datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate)
 to today's date 08:00 AM.

The following code is what I have done. However, that does not seems to be setting the datetime for the field.

```
$(function(){

    $('#started-at').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY LT',
        useCurrent: false,
        defaultDate: getDefaultStartAt()
    });
});

function getDefaultStartAt()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var day = d.getDate();
    var year = d.getFullYear();

    return new Date(year, month, day, 8, 0);
}
```

How can I correctly set the default value for bootstrap-datetimepicker?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005455/set-default-time-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: @AlexWells I am using similar answer to what you have posted but it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Your js code is fine.

You probably didn't include (or in wrong order) something from [minimal requirements](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/).
 `moment.js` maybe?

Or your html could be wrong.

Here you can see working example with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/5vv9chgx/