# How can I set a default hour in the DateTimePicker every time the user selects a date?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker, windows-forms-designer

I have two DateTimePickers, one named `FechaEntrada` and the other one `FechaSalida`.

I want to set `FechaEntrada.Value` to `"whatever_date_the_user_picked 00:00:00"` and `FechaSalida.Value` to `"whatever_date_the_user_picked 23:59:59"` every time the user chooses a date.

I need to compare both values from the dtpickers so I can fill a DatagridView from a DataBase with the values selected between these two dates.

In my windows form, the user CAN'T choose the hour, just the date. How can I do this? It seems simple but I can't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set default time in bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005455/set-default-time-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Comment: In the `ValueChanged` event: `[DateTimePicker].Value = [DateTimePicker].Value.Date + new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);`

Comment: The CustomFormat could be: `[DateTimePicker].CustomFormat = $"{CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern} HH:mm:ss";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it so the user sees/chooses only a date:

```
FechaEntrada.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
FechaEntrada.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; //or whatever date you want
FechaSalida.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
FechaSalida.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; //or whatever date you want
```

When you want to get the dates:

```
FechaEntrada.Value.Date; //"whatever_date_the_user_picked 00:00:00"
FechaSalida.Value.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1); //"whatever_date_the_user_picked 23:59:59".
```

`DateTimePicker.Value` returns a DateTime

Calling `DateTime.Date` gives the date as at midnight 00:00:00 (it's still a datetime) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.8

Calling `AddDays(1)` and `AddSeconds(-1)` will scroll the date forward one day and back one seconds so:

```
01-Jan-2000 12:34:56
01-Jan-2000 00:00:00 //.Date
02-Jan-2000 00:00:00 //.AddDays(1)
01-Jan-2000 23:59:59 //.AddSeconds(-1)
```

That's how the time changes for the salida..

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This makes 100% sense but I dont know why even when I set the value of ```dtpSalida``` to ```dtpSalida.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)``` the real DateTimePicker value still is 00:00:00. https://gyazo.com/70c181ca6aba07f35f21ccf2b9776c96,

Comment: In your code screenshot you have 2 important points missing: 1) you declare a variable called `value` and initialize it with the value from the date time picker, then you overwrite `value` with something else; **you never actually set the .Value of dtpSalida** make sure your code contains `dtpSalida.Value = ...` and 2) you're missing the **.Date** in `dtpSalida.Value.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)` - you only wrote `dtpSalida.Value.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)`. The **.Date** is critical, because without it every time your picker value is changed it will go one day forward and one minute back

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f40be1b40d47916c47eca05c5a753914 and still gives the same value :(

Comment: works for me - are you sure your event handlers fire?

Comment: note, because i wanted to show the date (not necessary) i put HH:mm:ss in my custom format too

Comment: Sorry but it's my first year studying C# and I dont really know how to check if my even handlers fire, and I also tried changing the format to HH:mm:ss

Comment: If I were (in my code screenshot) to click on the light grey area to the left of number 27 and 22 on the left, then a red dot appears in the light grey area; its a breakpoint. when running in debug mode, the code will stop when it reaches this point. if the code never stops, your event handlers arent linked to your valuechanged event

Comment: you can also check by showing the forms designer, clicking a datetimepicker and looking in the properties window lightning bolt to check there is something in the valuechanged cell

Comment: i made an example project that works as per my post. you can get it from https://gofile.io/?c=xRysPb

Comment: Oh you meant the breakpoints! Yes I already know how to use them, but thanks for your effort tho!