# get current date in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, utc

I'm using Datetimepicker of [XDAN](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker)
I want to set current date as default when page loaded.

I used `new Date()` and `getUTCFullYear` functions to get it.

But our current time is **utc+8** So theres difference in time, how can I solve this problem. I have tried `d.getUTCDate()+1` but difference between **utc** and **utc+8** is not **1 day**

This is my code:

```
jQuery(function(){
var d = new Date(),
date = (d.getUTCFullYear())+'-'+(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'+(d.getUTCDate());

 jQuery('#from-datepicker').datetimepicker({
     format:'Y-m-d 00:00:00',
     defaultTime:'00:00',
     formatTime: 'H:00',
     timepicker: false,
     mask: false,
     value: date,
  onShow:function( ct ){
   this.setOptions({
    maxDate:jQuery('#to-datepicker').val()?jQuery('#to-datepicker').val():false
   })
  },
 });
 jQuery('#to-datepicker').datetimepicker({
     format:'Y-m-d 23:59:59',
     defaultTime:'23:59',
     formatTime: 'H:59',
     timepicker: false,
     mask: false,
     value: date,
  onShow:function( ct ){
   this.setOptions({
    minDate:jQuery('#from-datepicker').val()?jQuery('#from-datepicker').val():false
   })
  },

 });
});


<input type="text" id="from-datepicker" name="from" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss">

<input type="text" id="to-datepicker" name="to" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss">
```

Comment: Refer [Get current date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398897/how-to-get-current-date-in-jquery)

Comment: Each `getUTC` method for `Date`s has an equivalent for local time – [`getUTCFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCFullYear) and [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear), etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, Its working now! I really appreciate your help! @SorangwalaAbbasali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working, Thanks guys for your support!

```
    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var day = d.getDate();
    var output = d.getFullYear() + '-' +
        ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
        ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;
```