# I am trying date format mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy in input type date

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

This is my code

```
 <input type="date" class="form-control float-right" value="dd-mm-yyyy" name="from_date_bk" id="from_date_bk">
```

And it returns like this
[image]

I want dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: You’re mixing jquery with php.  Php only works on the server, not in the browser. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398897/how-to-get-current-date-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your date is `2019-01-15`

```
var date = "2019-01-15";
var d = new Date(date);

var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();

var output = (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day +'-'+ (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +d.getFullYear();
```

**Result**

```
15-01-2019
```