# Convert and Read JSON date type in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I have a date in the form of:

```
"2012-10-11T00:00:00"
```

The date is returned from a ASP.NET Webservice as part of a JOSN object. How can I convert this date format to a Javascript date object and also write the date as follows to the screen:

**11/10/2012**

Thanks

Comment: `what = new Date("2012-10-11T00:00:00")` is insufficient for getting the Date object you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myDate = new Date("2012-10-11T00:00:00".replace(/T/," "));
var myDateString = myDate.getDate() + "/" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + myDate.getFullYear()
```

Answer (score 2):

For date conversions I use a plugin

[date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)

Be sure to include all the jquery files needed, there is plenty of documentation on how to implement this

If you do not want to use a plugin check this out [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Or this overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object)

Comment: I prefer a single command than using a plugin just for that. But I will take a look