# Changing Date format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var dt="29/05/2013"; //DD/MM/YYYY
```

I want to convert to yyyy/MM/dd format;

The approach I've used is:

```
var newdate=dt.getFullYear()+"/"+dt.getMonth()+"/"+dt.getDate();
```

Is there any simple approach to convert it with out using substring?

I don't want to use plugins by the way...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object

Comment: Searching first usual helps.

Comment: You don't need `Date` object, it's purely string manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var dt = "29/05/2013";
var newdt = dt.split('/').reverse().join('/');
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/4WGnC/

Comment: Nice, very clean and concise.

Comment: simple and excellent...

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a library to help you: http://www.datejs.com/ and http://momentjs.com/ are good libraries.

```
Date.parse ("29/05/2013").toString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Answer (score 2):

simply try like this

```
var a = dt.split("/");
var new_date = a[2]+'/'+a[1]+'/'+a[0];
alert(new_date);
```

Comment: It prints invalid date... Check your answer here http://jsfiddle.net/Njgx9/

Comment: Try my edit,I got some problem in my first ,but prevoius i worked with it

Comment: The edit would work; what surprises me is that you managed to get +3 on a bogus answer before =/

Comment: I had to double check that original code, I thought I had missed something in JS!

Comment: @Gautam3164 Make sure whether it works well before you post it an answer

Comment: I already told that,my previous will work...iam sure but i dont know where the mistake,and look I will trace it

Comment: @Jack Same surprise for me too .. The Upvoters didn't even check it

Comment: @PrasathK bec the upvoters know that it will work....you can check that solution even in forums.Dont blame the upvoters,they are not your freinds and not of mine...

Comment: That's crap! `Date` constructor only supports iso8601 reliably and `Date.toString()` doesn't use a date format argument; no matter now, but still good to remember.

Comment: @Gautam3164 Yupp it will work but yours doesn't ... Anyway cool buddy ...!!!

Comment: The fact that it worked for you before is probably because you were using date.js.

Comment: yah @Jack you are right and we are here to help only,and may be its my mistake bec i didnt used .parse of my date for the previuos ans,after I have seen jammaykam ans I see i forgotted

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery ui..

```
var newdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

**Look this Example:**

```
    var d = new Date ( "January 6, 1972" );

    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    document.write(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Your link is really helpful....

Comment: [10 useful date and time format](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3) and [Working with dates] (http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/) are both useful link! I am happy that you like it! thank you :)