# How to make fullcalendar to get current month events only?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar plugin to get and display holidays of a month via Ajax. The problem I am having, is that the method that retrieves the holidays accepts only a year and a month as parameter, not a date range.

When using month view of fullcalendar, the start and end parameter ranges from feb 23rd and Apr 6th. I need it to range from Mar 1st to Mar 31st. That way, I can only get year and month part to call the method.

This is what I tried but without success:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
        events: '/get_month_holidays',
        start: {
            month: new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(), (new Date()).getMonth(), 1)
        },
        end: {
            month: (new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(), (new Date()).getMonth() + 1, 1)) - 1
        },            
        buttonText: {
            today: 'hoy'
        }
    })
```

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I used:

```
        eventSources: [
            {
                url: '/get_month_holidays',
                type: 'POST',
                data: function() {
                    var fecha = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
                    return {
                        month: fecha.getMonth() + 1,
                        year: fecha.getFullYear()
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
```

And it worked. Thanks anyway.
Jaime

Comment: this works but it will still use the same url  `get_month_holidays`, which means that the entire events will be fetched, thus not reducing any speed.. what would be ideal is that if we clicked the "next/prev month" button, then it will only fetch the events for the current month rather than all the events at once.

Answer (score 2):

jstuardo's solution adds new parameters to the request so you end up with something like this:

```
http://your.api.com/events?month=8&year=2015&start=2015-07-27&end=2015-09-07
```

Which is quite confusing and requires you to change the API accordingly.

Better solution would be to change the default `start` and `end` parameters. You can achieve that using something like this:

```js
{
  url: baseUrl + '/events',
  startParam: null, //resetting default fullcalendar parameter
  endParam: null, //resetting default fullcalendar parameter
  data: function() {
    var date = $('#gc-calendar').fullCalendar('getDate')._d;
    var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
    var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

    firstDay = $filter('date')(firstDay, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    lastDay = $filter('date')(lastDay, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    //AngularJS way of changing the date format to yyyy-mm-dd

    return {
      start: firstDay,
      end: lastDay
    }
  }
}
```

This way your request looks like this:

```
http://your.api.com/calendar_orders?start=2015-08-01&end=2015-08-31
```

You can format the date to 'yyy-MM-dd' using any method you like. You can find a bunch of them here:
[Get String in YYYYMMDD format from JS date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object)