# Formatting String with pattern

Tags: javascript

I have a String variable who represent date

```
console.log(goDate); --> "23/12/2014"
```

how I could turn this variable like this..?:

```
console.log(goDate); --> "2014-12-23".
```

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: `("23/12/2014").replace(/\//g, '-')` it replace all '/' with '-'. but to reverse the result you need something more than a pattern

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var goDate = "23/12/2014"; // needs 2014-12-23
var newGoDate = goDate.split('/').reverse().join('-');
```