# How to convert a date to a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var tdt= new Date();
t=tdt.getFullYear()+"-"+(tdt.getMonth()+1)+"-"+tdt.getDate() // 2015-04-17
var tody = new Date(t).getTime(); /* 1429209000000 */ 
document.write(tody);
<script>
```

When I execute this code in Mozilla Firefox, I get 'NaN', but when I execute this code in Google Chrome, I get '1429209000000'. Does anyone know how to get the value '1429209000000' to be printed when I execute in Firefox and Opera?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use slashes as separators.

```
var tdt= new Date();
t=tdt.getFullYear()+"/"+(tdt.getMonth()+1)+"/"+tdt.getDate() // 2015-04-17
var tody = new Date(t).getTime(); /* 1429209000000 */ 
document.write(tody);
```