# converting string to json with date object on string

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to convert the string to json object but every time I tried I am getting error. Below is the my string format. All I did is passed the below string format to JSON.parse function but it did not work. If I passed the real string like "1/1/2014" instead of date object it works perfectly fine. What should I do to make this json conversion safely.

```
"[{ \"ID\": 0, \"ApplyDate\": new Date(2011, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0),
\"Phy\":37.74,\"Eng\": 40, \"Chem\": 37.62, \"math\": 39.17 },{ \"ID\": 1,
\"ApplyDate\": new Date(2010, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), \"Phy\": 37.15, \"Eng\":
37.99, \"Chem\": 36.51, \"math\": 37.51 }]";
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't JSON, so, JSON.parse cannot help you...

By the way:

1. the ID of the first object isn't escaped,
2. new Date(bla bla bla) isn't JSON, at least you should pass something like that `"new Date(2011, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0)"`

The best way to get a date is encoding it as a string...

```
(new Date()).toString();
```

if you are in love with your code, try to wrap the date object as a string and then exec an eval...

```
var a = eval("new Date()")
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is I dont think there is any other way around than `eval()`. The main problem is, that the sourcestring not is valid JSON but a literal-like structure that has been through some kind of escaping as string.

So remove the escapes first, `s` is the string from OP :

```
s = s.replace("\\", "");
```

convert it (back?) to literal with `eval()` :

```
var literal = eval(s);
```

now the `Date` objects inside the created literal actually works :

```
console.log(literal[0].ApplyDate.getFullYear());
```

outputs 2011

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hv7ar3qr/**

---

Now you can turn `literal` back to a valid JSON string with

```
var json = JSON.stringify(literal);
```

`json` will look like this :

```
[
    {
        "ID": 0,
        "ApplyDate": "2011-01-02T23:00:00.000Z",
        "Phy": 37.74,
        "Eng": 40,
        "Chem": 37.62,
        "math": 39.17
    },
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "ApplyDate": "2010-11-30T23:00:00.000Z",
        "Phy": 37.15,
        "Eng": 37.99,
        "Chem": 36.51,
        "math": 37.51
    }
]
```

`JSON.parse(json)` can be used to turn `json` into an iterable JSON object. A long way to go, where first step needs to be `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert `Date` to `String` then encode your `json`

```
new Date().toString(); //"Fri Nov 06 2015 19:37:51 GMT+0100"
```

You can change the format of `Date` with

```
var date = new Date();
date.format() //the format
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object) a method to get a `yyyymmdd` format

So if you have the object

```
var object = { date: theDate };
object.date = object.date.toString();
var json = JSON.stringify(object.date);
```

Comment: He is also not escaping some quotes.

Comment: I guess its the result of the bad conversion

Comment: this string stream is coming from the server side. Is there way to pick that field only at client side convert that to date ? If so how can I do this ?

Comment: You can follow @Hitmands suggestion, but it is not so safe to use eval string. You should avoid saving that date like this, it cause only problems, its not a correct json format