# Date format for REST API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I want to encode the date format to send the date through my REST API request. I have sample response as
createDate=1449092965474 
I don't know which format it is. Kindly help me decoding this date format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a javascript date in milliseconds since 1970. (Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

In this case:

```
new Date(1449092965474)
```

is

**Wed Dec 02 2015 22:49:25 GMT+0100**

I would recommend using ISO 8601 Format in your REST API.

- http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm
- http://apiux.com/2013/03/20/5-laws-api-dates-and-times/

Comment: how can i convert the YYYY-DD-MM to the milliseconds format? because API wants this date format.

Comment: You can use [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3067896/2391070). I personally use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) because of its great api.

Answer (score 0):

Dates written as numbers, specifies the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00. So if you convert it to normal date it will be Wed Dec 02 2015 16:49:25 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time).

Answer (score 0):

**Server Side (C#)**

Before Sending the date from your API.

Convert the date to a string.

like this .

`string YourNewDateObj = YourDateObj.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

**Client Side**

`new Date(1449092965474)`

This is give you response.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).