# convert date format from d/m/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in javascript

Tags: javascript, date-format

I am trying to convert a timestamp from `d/m/yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd` through `JavaScript`. Here is my code.

```
        var d = new Date();
        d.setDate(d.getDate()-5);
        temp = d.toLocaleString({minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping:false}).split(',')[0].split("/").reverse().join("-");
        console.log(temp)
```

I am getting output like this `2016-5-5`, but what I am suppose to get is `2016-05-05`. I tried options like `minimumIntegerDigits` with `toLocaleString` but its not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has got to be the hundredth question about converting dates using JS. Please next time, use google.

Comment: You're not really trying to convert *from* a particular format, you just want to get a date object as a string in the yyyy-mm-dd format. I wouldn't use `toLocaleString()` options, because not all browsers support that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
d.toLocaleString().split(',')[0].split("/").map( function(val, index, arr){ 
   if (index < arr.length - 1) 
   { 
     return ("0" + val).slice(-2); 
   } 
   return val;
}).reverse().join("-");
```

**DEMO**

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 5);

var output = d.toLocaleString().split(',')[0].split("/").map(function(val, index, arr) {
  if (index < arr.length - 1) {
    return ("0" + val).slice(-2);
  }
  return val;
}).reverse().join("-");

alert( output )
```

Comment: This gives me `2017-21-07` on my PC today!

Comment: What is the system date on your desktop?

Comment: As seen as the date/time of my comment.  It is now 2017-07-26T03:36Z.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
   var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
   var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
   var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
   return yyyy + '-' + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0])+ '-' + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]); // padding
  };

d = new Date();
d.yyyymmdd();
```

Related to this answer [Get String in YYYYMMDD format from JS date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object)