# Node js using wrong format on dates

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I created a page using handlebars where users can input a date, I works correctly and it shows the correct format on my mysql database, like this: 2017-04-01.

But when I get the date form the database using node js:

```
connection.query('SELECT date FROM tbl', function(err, rows, fields){
    console.log(rows);
});
```

I get this output:

```
Sat Apr 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)
```

Why does it include the time? but on the database is just the date. This is a problem for me because I need the date to output on a page and it takes too much space.

Comment: Just format your date

Comment: You can either use SQL or JS Date object to get the date into the correct format. It depends on which libraries you use and what the initial format of the SQL table is.

Comment: It's because (I'm assuming) it's parsing it to a [JS Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) which also stores the time, the good news is you can format it to only show the date values

Comment: @George how? can you please show me an example of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a JS Date object and by default, JS display you everything he knows about this date like time even if it is 0h0m0s (source : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date)

If you only want to display only the day for example, you can do this :

```
var myFormattedDate = date.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

Look here for explanation : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28431880/4541118

Comment: Did you just assume the JS Engine's gender?

Comment: My JS engine is a cat, whom I have to coerce with snacks and attention.

Comment: Well either way we can assume it's a binary gender _ba dum dum tish_

Comment: How do I exactly use that code? for example I have an object that has a date value, lets name in myDate. And when I output myDate I get the wrong format, how do I use var myFormattedDate = date.toISOString().substring(0, 10); to output myDate into correct format?

Comment: You just output `myFormattedDate` and not `myDate`