# I want to add one day to my date how can i do that

Tags: javascript

I want to add one day to my date how can I do that 
my date is     date = new Date();

```
date = new Date();
endDate = this.date.toString();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incrementing a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/incrementing-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

```
date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
endDate = this.date.toString();
```

[For more details](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setdate.asp)

Comment: it is giving me result like "Sat Aug 26 2017 11:30:28 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)" but i want it to be in YYYY/MM/DD

Comment: it is giving error " Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: can you please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object

Answer (score 1):

I think it is much nicer to use [`momentjs`](https://momentjs.com/) like:

```
 moment(new Date().toString(), "DD-MM-YYYY").add(1, 'days')
```

or even shorthand

```
moment().add(1, 'd');
```

checkout more on `.add()` operator [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it with [moment](https://momentjs.com/):

```
moment().add(1, 'day');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This way

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```js
date = new Date();
endDate = date;
endDate.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

alert(endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = new Date(); // Fri Feb 20 2015 19:29:31 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) 
var isoDate = new Date(now.getTime() - now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString();
//OUTPUT : 2015-02-20T19:29:31.238
```

Try This!