# How to extract only date in react-native

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

I am using `DateTimePicker` in my react-native app.But when i try to get date in my text field it returns me something like that `Monday June 21 2021 17:34:53 GMT....` but I want to get only date which is `2021:06:21` currently i am getting date like that `new Date()` and in my text I done like that `<Text>{date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")}</Text>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
yourDate.toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"")
```

in jsx code

```
<Text>{yourDate.toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"")}</Text>
```

base [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16714931/9161478)

OR

use [moment library](https://momentjs.com/)

```
<Text>{ moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY')}</Text>
```

Comment: at first, you did not introduce the moment library, which I think is a better solution. I have deleted my downvote after your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use moment
install moment

```
npm install moment --save
```

replace your text tag with this

```
<Text>{moment(date).format("MMM Do YY")}</Text>
```

ref : https://momentjs.com/

**OR**

you can also use toLocaleDateString() to get only date

```
<Text>{date.toLocaleDateString()}</Text>
```

**OR**

You can also convert first your date into string

```
    <Text>{date.toString().substr(4 ,12)}</Text>
```

Comment: `In most cases, you should not choose Moment for new projects` - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/ (moment is deprecated)

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend using https://momentjs.com/.

then you can write `moment(yourDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');` or whatever format you want.

Comment: `In most cases, you should not choose Moment for new projects.` - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/ (moment is deprecated)

Comment: Moment is not yet deprecated, but it's comming it's way.