# Javascript Date String Manipulation

Tags: javascript, string, date, javascript-objects

I have a date object`data = '2021-07-30T22:33:38.000Z'` . I need to manipulate the string a bit, for example create a string like `'abc2021-07-30T22:33:38.000Z`. If I use `'abc'+data`, the result would become `abcFri Jul 30 2021 15:33:38 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`

is there a way to convert data object to a string type without changing the format?

Comment: You can [Edit] your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `"abc" + data.toISOString()`. By default, turning a Date instance into a string gets you a string in the form you've seen, but there are various ways of getting other formats.

Comment: @RobG yea I chose the term badly; I meant a date that, well, looks like what they were complaining about. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [toString() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_date.asp) converts a Date object to a string.

Note: This method is automatically called by JavaScript whenever a Date object needs to be displayed as a string.

```js
 var d = new Date();
 console.log(d.toString())
```

[more on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object)