# How to get the data between two dates | NodsJs | MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create an api to get the data between two dates in NodeJS. My database is mongoDB, my data looks like this

```
_id:ObjectId("60ff19125474fa0ec45c2d1a")
username:"abc"
Date:"2021-7-26"
TimeIn:"2:02 PM"
TimeOut:"2:02 PM"

_id:ObjectId("6101f4a4676d8b2b743a2d58")
username:"abc"
Date:"2021-7-27"
TimeIn:"2:02 PM"
TimeOut:"2:02 PM"

_id:ObjectId("6102e1357ad1ed20d4642db0")
username:"abc"
Date:"2021-7-28"
TimeIn:"2:02 PM"
TimeOut:"2:02 PM"

_id:ObjectId("6104717cb025c025e8b2d15e")
username:"abc"
Date:"2021-8-01"
TimeIn:"2:02 PM"
TimeOut:"2:02 PM"
```

i want to fetch the data between two dates, i create an api to fetch data by date (single), need some modification to fetch it between two dates.

here is api to fetch data by date:

```
fetchHistorybydate =(req,res)=>{
  
  var HistoryList = []
      User.find({"username":req.body.username, "leave":{ $exists : false} },function(err,data){              
        for(var i =1 ;i<data.length;i++){
          var NDate = data[i].Date;
          if(NDate==req.body.date){
            HistoryList.push(data[i])
          }
        }
        if(err)
        {res.status(300).json("Error")}
          else{
          var token = jwt.sign({
            data: 'foobar'
          }, 'secret', { expiresIn: "30 minute"})
          res.status(200).json({AccessToken: token,data:HistoryList})
    }
  })
}
```

**for example:**

let say there are two calender on frontend one is for `Fromdate` and second is for `Todate`, if user select date from `Fromdate` calender this `2021-7-26` and from `Todate` calender this `2021-7-28` then it will only fetch the records from these dates.

the output should be, according to above data

```
_id:ObjectId("60ff19125474fa0ec45c2d1a")
username:"abc"
Date:"2021-7-26"
TimeIn:"2:02 PM"
TimeOut:"2:02 PM"

_id:ObjectId("6101f4a4676d8b2b743a2d58")
username:"abc"
Date:"2021-7-27"
TimeIn:"2:02 PM"
TimeOut:"2:02 PM"

_id:ObjectId("6102e1357ad1ed20d4642db0")
username:"abc"
Date:"2021-7-28"
TimeIn:"2:02 PM"
TimeOut:"2:02 PM"
```

Please help me how to do this.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What do you mean by **get the data between two dates**?

Comment: @mubin986 let me add example

Comment: @mubin986 i edited my code, please check, hope it is clear now!

Comment: It would be much easier if you store timestamps instead of actual date strings

Comment: Your code has very inconsistent spacing and indentation, and is too cramped. That makes it hard to read. You should fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to update the store Date object in the Date parameter of your database. After that, you'll be able to query by two date ranges. Currently, your Date parameter is a string, but, you have to convert it to a Date object.

**Here is the solution after converting into Date object:**

```
fetchHistorybydate = (req, res) => {
    var query = {
        username: req.body.username,
        Date: {
            $gte: new Date(req.body.Fromdate).toISOString(),
            $lte: new Date(req.body.Todate).toISOString()
        },
        leave: { $exists: false }
    }

    User.find(query, function (err, data) {
        if (err) { return res.status(300).json("Error") }
        else {
            return res.status(200).json({ data: data })
        }
    })
}
```

**Note:** No need to loop through the entire array again after retrieving the data. Because we already `query` from our database with the `$gte` and `$lte` parameters. Where `$gte` means `greater than or equal` and `$lte` means `less than or equal`.

You can also use `$gt` (greater than) and `$lt` (less than).

Comment: i got this error RangeError: Invalid time value at this line ```$gte: new Date(req.body.Fromdate).toISOString(),```

Comment: but when do it like this ```$gte:"2021-07-26"``` and ```$lte:"2021-07-30"``` i got data but excluding 26th date data it gets data from 28

Comment: i don't want to hard this, i will be passing the values from calender on frontend, please helpppp!

Comment: Just updated my answer, have a look, and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: i tried that way too, and got empty data, output: ```"data":[]```

Comment: **UPDATED ANSWER:** You have to update the store Date object in the Date parameter of your database. After that, you'll be able to query by two date ranges. Currently, your Date parameter is a string, but, you have to convert it to a Date object.

Comment: but could u please tell me how to store the date into this format ```2021-08-04``` when i udpate the datatype of date it stores the date like this ```2021-08-04T00:00:00.000Z```

Comment: Yeah, because the Date object also has a time in it. And, by default, the time is **12:00 AM**. That's why it's adding `00:00:00` which is basically 12:00 AM in 24 hours format.

Comment: but i don't want time with date, it will create problem for me when i will be fetching date on frontend from api, can we insert it without time?

Comment: Actually, it will not cause any issues. Because we're converting your front-end Date string to object with this line of code: `$gte: new Date(req.body.Fromdate).toISOString(),` and, it take cares the rest.

Comment: but i was fetching the date on other screen too, for some other purpose and it is causing problem, i just checked that, please help how to store it only date

Comment: you can convert the Date object to a string. You can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object